# Precedence of operators in python

Tags: python, operator-precedence

I was learning about the precedence of operators and I came across this:

">,>= are binary operators with left-sided binding, and their priority is greater than that shown by == and !=."
[image]

To verify I wrote the following statement

`print(False==0<0)` Output: `False`

But 0<0 gives False and False==False should give True.

Could you tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where did you get this table from?

Comment: Where did you find that table? All comparison operators have the same precedence and so the expression is evaluated L to R. (False==0 (true)) < 0 (false).

Comment: "Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise operation. Also unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:" "Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false)."

Comment: @Nicholas This is specifically *not* evaluated as `(False == 0) < 0`…!

Comment: Did you get this chart from GeeksForGeeks by chance? That seems like something they'd do.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks! I didn't know about this concept of chaining operators. Now it is clear. 
I have enrolled in the following course. The chart was given there.
https://www.netacad.com/courses/programming/pcap-programming-essentials-python